# Progress Bar for $command.ExecuteReader() in Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I would like to know if is possible to have create a progress bar for a $command.ExecuteReader().

Here is the scenario

I have a powershell code that create a insert query based on a input file.

The queries are saved on variables (4 query statements in 4 different variables)

Below the code that will actually EXECUTE the queries against an ORACLE database.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") | Out-Null
$connectionString = "User Id=USER;Password=PASS;Data Source=DATA_SOURCE;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()
foreach($query in (Get-Variable -Name str_query*)){
    $command = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand -ArgumentList $query.Value, $connection  
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
}
```

The queries are working, data is actually inserted in the database on correct tables. Everything regarding Powershell code and Oracle code is working as expected.

I would like to implement a Write-Progress for the $reader. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `Write-Progress` for your queries as they complete.

You would also need a counter to tell `Write-Progress` how far along you are based off the amount of queries there are.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") | Out-Null
$connectionString = "User Id=USER;Password=PASS;Data Source=DATA_SOURCE;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.Open()
$queries = Get-Variable -Name str_query*
foreach($query in $queries){
    $command = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand -ArgumentList $query.Value, $connection  
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

    $i = $i+1
    Write-Progress -Activity "Executing Queries" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($i/$queries.count*100)
}
```

Comment: What about a progress bar for the $reader = $command.ExecuteReader() itself? I didn't test your code yet but looks like Progress bar will be updated when the code move from one item to another item in the foreach right? I would like to measure the duration of the query utself. I'm aware about the max ammount to be the 100%.  In this case would be the number of records that I'm trying to insert in the table. Each of my queries are INSERT ALL with tons of recordst. I would like to give a progress bar while the INSERT ACTION is happening but I'm afraid that will be stuck in the reader execution

Comment: `Write-Progress` would only show the progress of the script execution as it progresses through the foreach. I’m not sure of a way to measure the progress of the actual queries from the Oracle client. You could probably write something to show each INSERT action and write a progress on that, but it would be a very long and complex script. Hopefully someone with deeper knowledge on Oracle connections could answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Peter... I had that working when i was executing the insert line-by-line. I mean, the query as a single insert line. But that became a problem since my query has 80.000+ inserts and it was taking long to run. Then I change to INSERT ALL which can easily handle the amount of insert with a better performance. But I'm paying the price about not been able to track the progress since the action is encapsulated in the $reader = $command.ExecuteReader(). I could use the Measure-Command but that will give me the time spent on that execution not a progress itself...